# Dynamically defined setter methods using define_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I use a lot of iterations to define convenience methods in my models, stuff like:

```
PET_NAMES.each do |pn|
define_method(pn) do
...
...
end
```

but I've never been able to dynamically define setter methods, ie:

```
def pet_name=(name)
...
end
```

using define_method like so:

```
define_method("pet_name=(name)") do
...
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a fairly full example of using `define_method` in a module that you use to extend your class:

```
module VerboseSetter
  def make_verbose_setter(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method("#{name}=") do |val|
        puts "@#{name} was set to #{val}"
        instance_variable_set("@#{name}", val)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend VerboseSetter

  make_verbose_setter :bar, :quux
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 5
f.quux = 10
```

Output:

```
@bar was set to 5
@quux was set to 10
```

You were close, but you don't want to include the argument of the method inside the arguments of your *call* to `define_method`.  The arguments go in the block you pass to `define_method`.

Answer (score 1):

Shoertly if you need it inside one class/module:
I use hash but you can put there array of elements etc.

```
PETS = {
  "cat" => "meyow",
  "cow" => "moo",
  "dog" => "ruff"
}

def do_smth1(v)
...
end

def do_smth(sound,v)
...
end

#getter
PETS.each{ |k,v| define_method(k){ do_smth1(v) } }

#setter
PETS.each{ |k,v| define_method("#{k}="){|sound| do_smth2(sound, v) }
```