# Is JRuby's implementation of Kernel#__method__ broken?

Tags: ruby, jruby, defects

This is the description of `Kernel#__method__` [according to Ruby-Doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) (emphasis added):

> Returns the name **at the definition of the current method** as a Symbol. If called outside of a method, it returns `nil`.

Now consider the following code snippet:

```
DEFINITION = proc { __method__ }

class C
  define_method :one, DEFINITION
  define_method :two, DEFINITION
end

o = C.new
```

When I run the following using MRI v1.8.7+ I'm getting the expected results:

```
o.one  #=> :one
o.two  #=> :two
```

However when I run the same code using JRuby 1.7+ (I haven't tested the previous versions):

```
o.one  #=> :two
o.two  #=> :two
```

Could this be considered a defect in JRuby's implementation or is it simply a different interpretation of `Kernel#__method__`?

Comment: See what happens in both contexts when you run `DEFINITION.call`.

Comment: In both cases the return value is `:two`.

Comment: maybe, just report this as a JRuby (compatibility) bug ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be a defect in JRuby's implementation of `__method__`, or it may be a bug in the implementation of `define_method`, or it may be strictly limited to the use of the two together. Look what happens if you cast the `Proc` object into a block by using the `&` operator:

```
DEFINITION = proc { __method__ }

class C
  define_method :one, &DEFINITION
  define_method :two, &DEFINITION
end

o = C.new
```

Now in MRI, as before:

```
o.one  #=> :one
o.two  #=> :two
```

However, in JRuby, it's fixed:

```
o.one  #=> :one
o.two  #=> :two
```

Given the internal implementation of MRI's `define_method`, which includes the handling of `Proc` arguments vs block arguments, if JRuby's is at all similar, it's also possible that that is where the problem could lie.

Either way, there are no parallels to be found by replacing `__method__` with `self`, `binding`, `object_id`, or any combination or permutation of them, so the issue is certainly localized to uses of `__method__`.

**UPDATE: Twist Ending**

[This was a known bug in MRI 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129798/kernel-method-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-in-dynamically-defined-methods), and JRuby's implementation mirrors that behavior.

Comment: The difference in the return value depending on the proc being cast into a code block or not seems to confirm that this is indeed a bug. I opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2212).