# How to define setter methods for all keys in a hash dynamically

Tags: ruby, methods, constructor, hashtable

I am writing a class which has a hash data member. The hash is initialized to have a set of keys with default values in the constructor.

How do I then generate setter methods corresponding to all the keys in the hash?

Please consider the following example:

```rb
class MyClass
    def initialize
        @hash = {
            "key1" => "N/A",
            "key2" => "N/A",
            "key3" => "N/A",
        }
    end
end

c = MyClass.new
c.key1 = "value1" # <--- How do I make something like this possible?
```

I imagine using `.each` method and then a block which uses `:define_method`.

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499247/dynamically-defined-setter-methods-using-define-method) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259051/ruby-setter-methods-for-hash-properties) but I wasn't able to deduct a solution to my question from them.

Comment: How about `MyClass = Struct.new(:key1, :key2, :key3)` ? Then you can do `c = MyClass.new; c.key1 = "value1"`

Comment: I want to keep the hash data member. This way it's ready to be converted to a json object with specific keys names. I need that to obey to a specific interface elsewhere.

Comment: FWIW `c.to_h` would return the hash. And if you `require 'json'` you'll also have a direct `c.to_json` method.

Comment: I see. I might consider if this would be a better approach. As you can probably guess I'm pretty new to Ruby. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a slight misunderstanding of Ruby's object model, which is probably what hinders you in finding the solution yourself.

> I am writing a class which has a hash data member.

Ruby doesn't have "data members". The `@hash` is not a "data member", it is an [*instance variable*](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables). And the instance variable is not a "member" of the class, it is a "member" of the *instance*, hence why it is called *instance* variable.

> The hash is initialized to have a set of keys with default values in the constructor.

Ruby doesn't have "constructors". In Ruby, instantiating a new object works like this:

The [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Class.html) class has an instance method called [`Class#allocate`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Class.html#method-i-allocate). As the name implies, this method allocates storage space for a new object. So, in your case, when we write something like

```ruby
new_object = MyClass.allocate
```

this would allocate storage space for a new instance of `MyClass`, instantiate a new instance of `MyClass` in that storage space, return the newly instantiated object and bind it to the local variable `new_object`.

This newly instantiated object is completely empty, it does not contain any data (other than the standard object metadata such as the reference to its class), which means in particular, it has no instance variables.

If you want to initialize the object with a pre-defined set of instance variables, you would send a message to the object telling it to initialize itself. This is typically accomplished with an *initializer* method. By convention, this method is called `initialize`.

(Note: it is slightly more than just a convention, there is a tiny bit of language magic here as well, in that `initialize` is created with `private` accessibility by default, unlike other methods which are created with `public` accessibility by default.)

So, after allocating our object with `Class#allocate`, we would now initialize it:

```ruby
new_object.initialize
```

or rather, since (as I mentioned above) `initialize` is `private` by default, we need to use [`BasicObject#__send__`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-__send__) to circumvent the access restriction:

```ruby
new_object.__send__(:initialize)
```

Note: if you are familiar with Objective-C, you might recognize this:

```objectivec
MyClass newObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Remembering to always initialize a newly instantiated object is somewhat cumbersome, so there is a helper factory method called [`Class#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Class.html#method-i-new), which looks more or less like this:

```ruby
class Class
  def new(...)
    obj = allocate
    obj.__send__(:initialize, ...)
    obj
  end
end
```

And there is a default implementation in [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-initialize) which has no parameters and does nothing:

```ruby
class BasicObject
  def initialize; end
end
```

This guarantees that `Class#new` will never fail with a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/NoMethodError.html) exception.

The important thing to realize here is that `allocate`, `initialize`, and `new` are methods like any other, they can be re-implemented (with the exception of `allocate` which needs to do some magic that can not be expressed in Ruby itself), they can be overridden, they can be monkey-patched, they can be intercepted, etc.

They are *not* "constructors", which are things that are kinda-sorta like methods but not really methods, with extra restrictions about inheritance, extra restrictions about what they are allowed to do, etc. They are just methods.

> How do I then generate setter methods corresponding to all the keys in the hash?
>
> […]
>
> I imagine using `.each` method and then a block which uses `:define_method`.

The simplest and smallest change to your existing code would be something like this:

```ruby
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @hash = { key1: 'N/A', key2: 'N/A', key3: 'N/A' }

    @hash.each_key do |key|
      self.class.define_method(:"#{key}=") do |value|
        @hash[key] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, there is a problem with this: as explained above, `MyClass#initialize` is an instance method that is run by `MyClass::new` every time you create a new instance of `MyClass`. This means that every time the user creates a new object (except the first time), they will be annoyed with a plethora of method re-definition warnings:

```ruby
MyClass.new

MyClass.new
# my_class.rb:6: warning: method redefined; discarding old key1=
# my_class.rb:6: warning: previous definition of key1= was here
# my_class.rb:6: warning: method redefined; discarding old key2=
# my_class.rb:6: warning: previous definition of key2= was here
# my_class.rb:6: warning: method redefined; discarding old key3=
# my_class.rb:6: warning: previous definition of key3= was here

MyClass.new
# my_class.rb:6: warning: method redefined; discarding old key1=
# my_class.rb:6: warning: previous definition of key1= was here
# my_class.rb:6: warning: method redefined; discarding old key2=
# my_class.rb:6: warning: previous definition of key2= was here
# my_class.rb:6: warning: method redefined; discarding old key3=
# my_class.rb:6: warning: previous definition of key3= was here
```

You can imagine that, in an application which might create dozens, hundreds, or even millions of objects, this can get really annoying really fast.

You could fix this problem by defining the writer methods on the singleton classes of the instantiated objects using [`Object#define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method) like this:

```ruby
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @hash = { key1: 'N/A', key2: 'N/A', key3: 'N/A' }

    @hash.each_key do |key|
      define_singleton_method(:"#{key}=") do |value|
        @hash[key] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But that is not an elegant solution: the point of singleton methods is that each object can have its own distinct set of methods. But if you define the same methods for all objects, then what's the point? Just define the methods in the class, *once*, for all objects.

The way to handle this is to move the creation of the methods out of the initializer method and only run it once when the class itself is created, something like this:

```ruby
class MyClass
  DEFAULT_HASH = { key1: 'N/A', key2: 'N/A', key3: 'N/A' }.freeze
  private_constant :DEFAULT_HASH

  DEFAULT_HASH.each_key do |key|
    define_method(:"#{key}=") do |value|
      @hash[key] = value
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @hash = DEFAULT_HASH.dup
  end
end
```

There is some duplication in the creation of the default hash, which we could refactor like this:

```ruby
class MyClass
  DEFAULT_HASH_KEYS = %i[key1 key2 key3].freeze
  DEFAULT_HASH_VALUE = 'N/A'
  DEFAULT_HASH = DEFAULT_HASH_KEYS.zip([DEFAULT_HASH_VALUE].cycle).to_h.freeze
  private_constant :DEFAULT_HASH_KEYS, :DEFAULT_HASH_VALUE, :DEFAULT_HASH

  DEFAULT_HASH_KEYS.each do |key|
    define_method(:"#{key}=") do |value|
      @hash[key] = value
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @hash = DEFAULT_HASH.dup
  end
end
```

However, all of this functionality already exists in the form of the [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Struct.html) class:

```ruby
MyClass =
  Struct.new(:key1, :key2, :key3) do
    def initialize
      super(*members.map { 'N/A' })
    end
  end
```

This is all you need to do to get the desired behavior. In fact, this gives you a lot more than just the desired behavior. It also gives you a sensible implementation of [equality (`Struct#==`)](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Struct.html#method-i-3D-3D) without you having to define it yourself, it gives you a sensible implementation of deconstruction for [pattern matching](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html) in the form of ([`Struct#deconstruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Struct.html#method-i-deconstruct) and [`Struct#deconstruct_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Struct.html#method-i-deconstruct_keys)) without you having to define it yourself, etc. You will also have *readers* defined in addition to the *writers*, i.e. `MyClass#key1`, `MyClass#key2`, and `MyClass#key3`, in addition to `MyClass#key1=`, `MyClass#key2=`, and `MyClass#key3=`.

Note: one important thing to understand about `Struct` is that [`Struct::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Struct.html#method-c-new) does *not* return an *instance* of `Struct`, but a *subclass* of `Struct`, i.e. an instance of `Class`. This is unusual: normally, sending the `new` message to a class will return an instance of that class, e.g. `Array.new` will return an `Array`, `Hash.new` will return a `Hash`, `MyClass.new` will return a `MyClass`, and so on. But `Struct.new` will return a `Class` which is a *subclass* of `Struct`.

Related to `Struct`, there is also the [`ostruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/stdlibs/ostruct/OpenStruct.html) library in the Ruby standard library, which is however more similar to a `Hash` than a `Struct`.

And there is the [`Data`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Data.html) class, which is similar to `Struct` but for immutable value objects.

Comment: Hurray for Structs. They also come with a `to_h` method and a `to_json` method (when `require`d)

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. I decided to go with struct :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve the problem, with different pros/cons.

1. You can use `define_singleton_method`, (almost) as you suggested (this solution has a serious drawback, I'll get back to it later):

```rb
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @hash = {
        "key1" => "N/A",
        "key2" => "N/A",
        "key3" => "N/A",
    }

    @hash.each do |key, value|
      self.define_singleton_method "#{key}=" do |value|
        @hash[key] = value
      end
    end
  end
end

c = MyClass.new #=> #<MyClass:0x00000001451b76c8 @hash={"key1"=>"N/A", "key2"=>"N/A", "key3"=>"N/A"}>
c.key1 = "foo"
c #=> #<MyClass:0x00000001451b76c8 @hash={"key1"=>"foo", "key2"=>"N/A", "key3"=>"N/A"}>
```

The biggest pros of this method is its explicitness - we do create "real" instance methods.

The biggest disadvantage of this approach is that it creates setters only for the initial set of keys. If you add keys later there will be no setters for them. If you remove keys later, there the setters will be still defined and re-add keys silently when called (this might be not what you expect).

2. Another way to solve the problem is using `method_missing`:

```rb
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @hash = {
        "key1" => "N/A",
        "key2" => "N/A",
        "key3" => "N/A",
    }
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if name.end_with?("=") && @hash.key?(name[0..-2])
      @hash[name[0..-2]] = args.first
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name)
    (name.end_with?("=") && @hash.key?(name[0..-2])) || super
  end
end

c = MyClass.new #=> #<MyClass:0x000000012e3ba090 @hash={"key1"=>"N/A", "key2"=>"N/A", "key3"=>"N/A"}>
c.key1 = "foo"
c #=> #<MyClass:0x000000012e3ba090 @hash={"key1"=>"foo", "key2"=>"N/A", "key3"=>"N/A"}>
```

It works with the actual data structure, checking if the key exists before delegating the call. Trying to set non-existing key will raise no method error.

The thing to remember here is that if you ever create an instance method with name `key=` where `key` is the key inside `@hash`, this setter magic won't work for this key (method_missing will never be called for this key).
Another drawback of the 2nd approach compared to the 1st one to keep in mind is that we don't actually create setters per se. So inspecting instance's methods won't expose them.

Comment: With your first option, you are creating the setter methods on the class. Thus, each new instance will (1) (re-)define the methods on the class again and (2) if you change the code and use a `@hash` with different keys, the methods of any instance will be defined for all instances. To solve this, you may want to use `self.define_singleton_method` instead to just define the method in the individual instance's singleton class.

Comment: It doesn't happen in the code above because as you see the hash is *hardcoded* in the initializer (and I didn't change that), so in fact all the instances are created with the same set of keys and thus setters are re-created the same. But if the initializer would be parametrized with the hash it would be exactly as you said, this is a good point. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The code before the edit would also generate tons of method redefinition warnings for every instance except the first one. More precisely, over the lifetime of the application, it will generate 2 * (#instances - 1) * @hash.keys.size warning messages (since each method redefinition generates two warnings, one telling you the overwritten method and one telling you the original method).